# lost with comparison expression in javaScript

Tags: javascript, comparison

I'm doing a challenge and I've been given this to resolve but I can't find the error.

> Declare a variable named speed and set it equal to 90.
>
> Then declare a second variable named busExplodes and assign it the
> result of a comparison expression that checks if speed is lesser than
> 80.
>
> Print the result to the console.

```
var speed = 90;
var busExplodes = 80 < 90;
console.log (busExplodes);
```

I get this error: `>>>>Code is incorrect Your condition should evaluate if speed is lesser than 80.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `var busExplodes = speed < 80;`

Comment: To add to @Unmitigated's comment. Your code does't implement the instructions which is to compare the variable `speed` to 80. Instead you are comparing 80 to 90.

Comment: Alan thank u so much, simple as it is hahaha!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this task with the following JavaScript code:

```
// Declare a variable named speed and set its value to 90
let speed = 90;

// Declare a second variable named busExplodes and assign it the result of a comparison expression that checks if speed is less than 80
let busExplodes = speed < 80;

// Print the result to the console
console.log(busExplodes);
```